# Scene Kit: Set camera rotation from lookAt vector and up vector

Tags: scenekit, ios10.3

I wanted to ask you how to set the local camera rotation from the lookAt vector and the up vector in SceneKit? Is there any function for it like in Unity3D?
Further I wanted to ask if the camera can be rotated relative to the camera node? As I understand it, the coordinate system from the camera is different to the global coordinate system (z is inverse).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There's a lot of do-hickey involved in getting cameras to work well in iOS 10 and earlier SceneKit. If you haven't seen it, Apple has finally figured this is a ridiculous situation and added a lot of useful stuff to the cameras in iOS 11... if you can stall your project out until that release, check this out, otherwise don't look at it, as it will only make you sad:: **What's New In Scene Kit** :: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/604/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new util methods mentioned by Confused can be found on the `SCNNode` class. The one you're most likely interested in is [`simdLook(at:up:localFront:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881848-simdlook%20simdLook(at:up:localFront:))

```
func simdLook(at worldTarget: vector_float3, 
              up worldUp: vector_float3, 
              localFront: simd_float3)
```